# How do I turn the status bar off?

Tags: iphone

New view based project in XCode
Go to main.xib and view.xib respectively
In each case set status bar to none in attributes section for view

Not sure why it still shows both on simulator and on platform?

Have looked for something in code, but don't see what else is calling this?

Anybody know how to turn the status bar off?

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out...

Using Snow Leopard and the XCode 3.2, you simply edit the Apps Info.plist.

Right click the open Info.plist and add a row.

Select "Status Bar Style" from the drop down list. In the column to the right type in UIStatusBarHidden.

To affect this more dynamically this can be used instead:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; should hide the status bar.

// :)

Answer (score 2):

The status bar off in interface builder does not make it go away, use  UIApplications - (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:animated: